# VIM Always Use Tabbed Pages

Tags: vim

I would like a command that I can put in my ~/.vimrc file that will make vim always open in tabbed pages mode without having to pass the `-p` on the command line.

Is there such a command?  If not, is there a better way to do this.  Currently, I'm using

```
alias vi='vim -p'
```

in my bash profile.

Thanks.....

Comment: Do you want all your buffers to always open in a new tab?

Comment: Your alias is the best solution. That said, [you are probably misusing tab pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs/26710166#26710166).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the following in `~/.vimrc` and `source ~/.vimrc`

```
au VimEnter * if !&diff | tab all | tabfirst | endif
```

works as being mentioned [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/310/how-do-i-make-opening-new-tabs-the-default)

---

or set an alias in you rc file e.g. `~/.bashrc`. This is the approach I take.

```
alias vim='vim -p'
alias vi='vim -p'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `:au BufAdd,BufNewFile * nested tab sball` to your vimrc as per [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_every_buffer_in_its_own_tabpage).

Edit:

```
:au BufAdd,BufNewFile,BufRead * nested tab sball
```

This will always open all buffers in a new tab if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't what I'm looking for.  With this, if I run 'vim file1 file2' it only opens file1.  It doesn't open each file in it's own tab.  I'm looking for a vimrc substitute for 'vim -p'.

Comment: This one (the edited version) opens the first file once and each additional file twice.