# Which is better approach for opening tabs by default in vim

Tags: vim

`vim -p` opens, by default, in tabs viewport. Also having following `autocommand`

```
au VimEnter * if !&diff | tab all | tabfirst | endif
```

in `vimrc` accomplices the same thing as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822816/vim-always-use-tabbed-pages/34831482#34831482). I am just wondering which is better approach in terms of performance

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean by "better"?

Comment: @MartinS, Updated accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Related post: [Using Vim's tabs like buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/102384/438329)

Comment: Not opening tab pages if they are not strictly needed is a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a performance perspective, **it shouldn't matter**. The startup code (for `-p`) first creates all necessary tab pages, then fills them with the arguments. The `:tab` is a modifier to the `:all` command, which iterates over all arguments and opens a new tab page for each. As this all happens in native (compiled C) code, both should scale about the same with the number of arguments.

#### Why?

Many other applications use the *one tab per document* paradigm. While you can do that in Vim, too, you're missing out on window splits, which are very useful. Think of *diff mode*, the built-in `:help`, the *preview window*, *command-line window*, *quickfix* and *location lists*. All are opened in a split window, so you have to learn basic window navigation, anyway. @PeterRincker has already posted a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers) to a related question whose answers go into more detail (should you need more convincing arguments...)