# how to associate tabs for each split window in vim

Tags: vim

I was checking the recent atom editor with the vim plugin, and one feature that i really liked is that each split window can have tabs associated to it, i would like to know if this is possible with the vim , are there any plugins in vim to do this? 
I have attached an image below to describe the windows and tabs.

TIA

[image: image attached]

Comment: so you want to have two tabs that show two identical layouts?

Comment: @perreal after a split, i want to assign tabs to each split window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

In Vim, tab pages are containers for windows and windows are containers for buffers and there's no way around that.

Comment: You should link to your own answer to this frequent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs/26710166#26710166