# Default Vim to always open help in a new tab

Tags: linux, vim, tabs

Since I've started using Vim tabs (I'm a bit late to the game since they've been there since 2009!), I find I'd like most thing to default to tabs, so I always open files with `vim -p file1 file2` etc. I would like `:help` / `:h` to always open in tabs also. I can do `:tab help ctrl-w` or `:tab h ctrl-w` but how can I use `.vimrc` to always default `:h` or `:help` to open in a new tab?

Additionally, is there a way to take an open file and push it into a tab, or to tell vim to take *all* open buffers and dynamically shift them all into tabs?

Comment: I know it's quite the opposite what you are asking, but just in case: [Why do Vim experts prefer buffers over tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26710166/10247460)

Comment: It's of interest, thanks, though I've also been reading a lot on using both buffers and tabs. Both are elegant and clean systems when using Vim I think, though I'm tending towards tabs just for the visibility of what's open always being there.

Comment: To move window to tab is `:h CTRL-W_T`. To open help in tab - just say 'no'.

Comment: hmm, `Ctrl-W, T` doesn't seem to do that (help says "go to top window"). I'd like to open help in tabs, much more convenient to flip between them. I get that you have a personal preference Matt, but what is your reasoning (curious to know why you are so opposed)? Do you prefer tiled windows, or do you just not use anything but buffers?

Comment: Everyone *always* uses buffers no matter what. Windows are an abstraction one uses *on top* of buffers and tab pages are yet another abstraction *on top* of windows. One should use the right abstraction level for the task.

Comment: Well, there are *right abstractions* and *convenience*. If I'm in a script editing it and I just want to open vim help file in a tab alongside that in another tab, what is the harm?

Comment: The context switching. You are in context A and you wonder how to do X so you open the doc for X in a new context B so you end up with two contexts where you can't reference anything from the other context without switching. Yes, mashing `gt` and `gT` is easy, but context switching has a much heavier toll than eyeballing to the right and to the left because you must bring that context with you at every trip.

Answer (score 4):

1. "take an open file and push it into a tab"

   You can do that with this normal mode command:

   ```
   <C-w>T
   ```

   or this equivalent Ex command:

   ```
   :wincmd T
   ```

   See `:help ctrl-w_t` and `:help :wincmd`.
2. "`:h` to always open in tabs"

   You only need to put the aforementioned Ex command in `after/ftplugin/help.vim`:

   ```
   wincmd T
   ```

Comment: I can get `:wincmd T` to work thanks, but not `<C-w>T` for some reason (just does nothing when I try it). I will explore further on that. 

What does `after/ftplugin/help.vim` mean? I do not find a directory called `after`, where is that?

I was thinking that someone could be put into `.vimrc` to redefine `:h / :help` so that they always open in a new tab. I'll use this `after/ftplugin/help/vim` maybe but I don't know where that is?

Comment: "(just does nothing when I try it)" <-- what did you try, *exactly*? "What does `after/ftplugin/help.vim` mean?" <-- It's a path to a file under your `~/.vim` directory. Create it and its hierarchy if they don't exist. "redefine `:h / :help`" <-- you can't redefine built-in Ex commands.

Comment: ok, I created `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim` and I put `wincmd T` in there. I closed vim and reopened, then I did `:h ctrl-w`. Help opens as normal, and fails to open in a new tab. For `<C-w>T`, I opened 2x files in vim, so that `:ls` shows them, then in one file, I do `Ctrl-w` then `t` and nothing happens. No file is moved into a tab. Sorry if I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: @YorSubs 1) You must have `filetype plugin on` to make "ftplugin" working 2) It's `Ctrl-W` and `T`, not `t`.

Comment: You mean I just type `filetype plugin on` ? I tried Ctrl-W then T (shift-t), still nothing. It says "Already only one window" but there are 4 buffers when I type `:ls` ! I'm a bit confused how I put this buffer into a tab ...

Comment: Tab consists of windows, not buffers.

Comment: Gotcha, that works, thanks, I get the distinction now. I guess another way to describe what I was wondering was, if I open 5 files by doing `vim *` or some other way, that I end up with 5 buffers, then I want to spray them out to 5 tabs, or indeed, the reverse, to compress all tabs into one window with 5 buffers?

Comment: For the the former, see `:help :argdo` and `:help :tab`. For the latter, since buffers are global, see `:help :tabdo` and `:help :close`.

Comment: Even though Matt sort of explained the situation, just to be clear, in order for the `CTRL-W T` shortcut to move a buffer to a tab, you must have at least two windows open in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autocmd` to always open help in a new tab

```
" This won't work if you open the same help file more than once
autocmd FileType help wincmd T

" This works
autocmd BufEnter *.txt if &filetype == 'help' | wincmd T | endif
```

Or you can define a new command to only open it in a new tab, when in a small screen or there are many to read, for example.
With the following, you can use `:Tabhelp ...`.

```
function! Tabhelp(arg)
  execute 'tab help '.a:arg 
endfunction

command -nargs=? -complete=help Tabhelp call Tabhelp(<q-args>)
```